# How do I reset the scale/zoom of a web app on an orientation change on the iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, orientation

When I start my app in portrait mode, it works fine. Then I rotate into landscape and it's scaled up.  To get it to scale correctly for the landscape mode I have to double tap on something twice, first to zoom all the way in (the normal double tap behavior) and again to zoom all the way out (again, the normal double tap behavior).  When it zooms out, it zooms out to the correct NEW scale for landscape mode.

Switching back to portrait seems to work more consistently; that is, it handles the zoom so that the scale is correct when the orientation changes back to portrait.

I am trying to figure out if this is a bug? or if this is  something that can be fixed with JavaScript?

With the viewport meta content, I am setting the initial-scale to 1.0 and I am NOT setting minimum or maximum scale (nor do I want to).  I am setting the width to device-width.

Any ideas? I know a lot of people would be grateful to have a solution as it seems to be a persistent problem.

Comment: A perfect solution: No javascript! http://stackoverflow.com/a/8727440/805787

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Jeremy Keith ([@adactio](http://twitter.com/adactio)) has a good solution for this on  his blog [Orientation and scale](http://adactio.com/journal/4470/)

Keep the Markup scalable by not setting a maximum-scale in markup.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Then disable scalability with javascript on load until *gesturestart* when you allow scalability again with this script:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
    var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
    if (viewportmeta) {
        viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0';
        document.body.addEventListener('gesturestart', function () {
            viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6';
        }, false);
    }
}
```

---

**Update 22-12-2014:**
On an iPad 1 this doesnt work, it fails on the eventlistener. I've found that removing `.body` fixes that:

```
document.addEventListener('gesturestart', function() { /* */ });
```

Comment: Surely this is better than disabling zoom?! The best fix I've found yet :)

Comment: Hmm, this still disables the ability to zoom. Does anyone have a simple solution that doesn't do this?

Comment: It works, however I observed that the issue starts again if i use pinch-zoom gesture and then rotate the screen. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: It works.  However, I've noticed the user has to pinch open twice in order to zoom.  I'm guessing this is because the `maximum-scale=1.0` stays in effect after the gesture starts.  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This doesn't work for 2 reasons:
1) it disables gesturestart number 1, causing the user to need to gesture twice.
2) it breaks after the user doubles the first gesture, so it really only works if the user never gestures at all.   
 -- everyone should look at Andrew Ashbacher's solution below.  It really works.

Answer (score 19):

[Scott Jehl](http://scottjehl.com/) came up with a fantastic solution that uses the accelerometer to anticipate orientation changes.  This solution is very responsive and does not interfere with zoom gestures.

https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix

> How it works: This fix works by listening to the device's
>   accelerometer to predict when an orientation change is about to occur.
>   When it deems an orientation change imminent, the script disables user
>   zooming, allowing the orientation change to occur properly, with
>   zooming disabled. The script restores zoom again once the device is
>   either oriented close to upright, or after its orientation has
>   changed. This way, user zooming is never disabled while the page is in
>   use.

Minified source:

```
/*! A fix for the iOS orientationchange zoom bug. Script by @scottjehl, rebound by @wilto.MIT License.*/(function(m){if(!(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(navigator.platform)&&navigator.userAgent.indexOf("AppleWebKit")>-1)){return}var l=m.document;if(!l.querySelector){return}var n=l.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]"),a=n&&n.getAttribute("content"),k=a+",maximum-scale=1",d=a+",maximum-scale=10",g=true,j,i,h,c;if(!n){return}function f(){n.setAttribute("content",d);g=true}function b(){n.setAttribute("content",k);g=false}function e(o){c=o.accelerationIncludingGravity;j=Math.abs(c.x);i=Math.abs(c.y);h=Math.abs(c.z);if(!m.orientation&&(j>7||((h>6&&i<8||h<8&&i>6)&&j>5))){if(g){b()}}else{if(!g){f()}}}m.addEventListener("orientationchange",f,false);m.addEventListener("devicemotion",e,false)})(this);
```

Comment: Nice! Looks like an elegant solution.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer!!!!  I wish I saw this first before wasting an hour on the solutions above :)

Comment: after further testing this is kind of an unreliable solution :( it is inconsistent, and after looking through the code i can see why... the "threshold" of movement defined is not always reached, especially if you're holding the ipad at an angle while rotating

Comment: Could have nasty consequences for anyone who uses rotation lock... they could hold the phone at a certain angle and lose the ability to zoom - the user would have no idea why

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, and setting the maximum-scale=1.0 worked for me.

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments this does disable user zoom except when the content exceeds the width-resolution. As mentioned, this might not be wise. It might also be desired in some cases.

The viewport code:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

Comment: Nice solution. Does a good job keeping the page at a constant zoom level (relative to the width of the device) through orientation changes. Thanks for sharing it!

Comment: the downside is that disabled users can't zoom in on your site!

Comment: I noticed that all of these methods seem to prevent media-query based CSS from registering the new device width properly (ex: @media all and (max-width: 479px)

Comment: killing user zoom is a very bad idea.  see Andrew Ashbacher's solution below

Comment: Not sure about iPhone, but on iPad this doesn't solve the issue, it just prevents the user from being able to manually zoom out when the browser zooms in on orientation change.

Comment: There are some situations where you want to remove user zoom. This was the best solution I found.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the width set in the viewport :

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;
 maximum-scale=1.0;" />
```

And then change the orientation it will randomly zoom in sometimes (especially if you are dragging on the screen) to fix this don't set a width here I used :

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;
minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

This fixes the zoom whatever happens then you can use either window.onorientationchange event or if you want it to be platform independant (handy for testing) the [window.innerWidth](http://ajaxian.com/archives/iphone-web-development-tips-and-official-documentation-released) method.

Comment: Would this also prevent users from zooming in and out manually?

Answer (score 1):

MobileSafari supports the [`orientationchange`](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW16) event on the `window` object. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to directly control the zoom via JavaScript. Perhaps you could dynamically write/change the `meta` tag which controls the viewport — but I doubt that would work, it only affects the initial state of the page. Perhaps you could use this event to actually resize your content using CSS. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I tried dynamically changing the meta tag viewport values and it did nothing. 

It seems to me that if you rotate into Landscape you want it to zoom correctly to keep the scale so that the page fits into the Safari window.  It seems very odd to me that this is not the default behavior!

Answer (score 1):

I created a working demo of a landscape/portrait layout but the zoom must be disabled for it to work without JavaScript:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ipad-layout-with-landscape-portrait-modes

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this function in my project.

```
function changeViewPort(key, val) {
    var reg = new RegExp(key, "i"), oldval = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').content;
    var newval = reg.test(oldval) ? oldval.split(/,\s*/).map(function(v){ return reg.test(v) ? key+"="+val : v; }).join(", ") : oldval+= ", "+key+"="+val ;
    document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').content = newval;
}
```

so just addEventListener:

```
if( /iPad|iPhone|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ){
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() { 
        changeViewPort("maximum-scale", 1);
        changeViewPort("maximum-scale", 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elisabeth you can change viewport content dynamically by adding the "id" property to the metatag:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="view" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Then you just can call by javascript:

```
document.getElementById("view").setAttribute('content','user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=10');
```

Comment: @bridgestew if you wanna change zoom or viewport dinamically use the subview scrollview contained into the uiwebview. I added a sample snipet on other thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890673/iphone-uiwebview-width-does-not-fit-after-zooming-operation-uiinterfaceorientat/5015129#5015129)

Comment: @Elisabeth does it work for you ? It doesn't reset the zoom when switching in landscape mode for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a new workaround, different from any other that I have seen, by disabling the native iOS zoom, and instead implementing zoom functionality in JavaScript.

An excellent background on the various other solutions to the zoom/orientation problem is by Sérgio Lopes: [A fix to the famous iOS zoom bug on orientation change to portrait](https://github.com/sergiolopes/ios-zoom-bug-fix/#other-solutions).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Robocat mobile Safari zoom fix</title>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #container {
            -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
            -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
            /* shrink-to-fit needed so can measure width of container http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents */
            display: inline-block;
            *display: inline;
            *zoom: 1;
        }
        #zoomfix {
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="zoomfix" disabled="1" tabIndex="-1">
    <div id="container">
        <style>
            table {
                counter-reset: row cell;
                background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_010.jpg);
            }
            tr {
                counter-increment: row;
            }
            td:before {
                counter-increment: cell;
                color: white;
                font-weight: bold;
                content: "row" counter(row) ".cell" counter(cell);
            }
        </style>
        <table cellspacing="10">
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
            <tr><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td><td>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
    (function() {
        var viewportScale = 1;
        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        var scale, originX, originY, relativeOriginX, relativeOriginY, windowW, windowH, containerW, containerH, resizeTimer, activeElement;
        document.addEventListener('gesturestart', function(event) {
            scale = null;
            originX = event.pageX;
            originY = event.pageY;
            relativeOriginX = (originX - window.pageXOffset) / window.innerWidth;
            relativeOriginY = (originY - window.pageYOffset) / window.innerHeight;
            windowW = window.innerWidth;
            windowH = window.innerHeight;
            containerW = container.offsetWidth;
            containerH = container.offsetHeight;
        });
        document.addEventListener('gesturechange', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (originX && originY && event.scale && event.pageX && event.pageY) {
                scale = event.scale;
                var newWindowW = windowW / scale;
                if (newWindowW > containerW) {
                    scale = windowW / containerW;
                }
                var newWindowH = windowH / scale;
                if (newWindowH > containerH) {
                    scale = windowH / containerH;
                }
                if (viewportScale * scale < 0.1) {
                    scale = 0.1/viewportScale;
                }
                if (viewportScale * scale > 10) {
                    scale = 10/viewportScale;
                }
                container.style.WebkitTransformOrigin = originX + 'px ' + originY + 'px';
                container.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale3d(' + scale + ',' + scale + ',1)';
            }
        });
        document.addEventListener('gestureend', function() {
            if (scale && (scale < 0.95 || scale > 1.05)) {
                viewportScale *= scale;
                scale = null;
                container.style.WebkitTransform = '';
                container.style.WebkitTransformOrigin = '';
                document.getElementById('viewport').setAttribute('content', 'user-scalable=no,initial-scale=' + viewportScale + ',minimum-scale=' + viewportScale + ',maximum-scale=' + viewportScale);
                document.body.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale3d(1,1,1)';
                // Without zoomfix focus, after changing orientation and zoom a few times, the iOS viewport scale functionality sometimes locks up (and completely stops working).
                // The reason I thought this hack would work is because showing the keyboard is the only way to affect the viewport sizing, which forces the viewport to resize (even though the keyboard doesn't actually get time to open!).
                // Also discovered another amazing side effect: if you have no meta viewport element, and focus()/blur() in gestureend, zoom is disabled!! Wow!
                var zoomfix = document.getElementById('zoomfix');
                zoomfix.disabled = false;
                zoomfix.focus();
                zoomfix.blur();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    zoomfix.disabled = true;
                    window.scrollTo(originX - relativeOriginX * window.innerWidth, originY - relativeOriginY * window.innerHeight);
                    // This forces a repaint. repaint *intermittently* fails to redraw correctly, and this fixes the problem.
                    document.body.style.WebkitTransform = '';
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It could be improved, but for my needs it avoids the major drawbacks that occur with all the other solutions I have seen. So far I have only tested it using mobile Safari on an iPad 2 with iOS4.

The focus()/blur() is a workaround to prevent the occasional lockup of the zoom functionality which can occur after changing orientation and zooming a few times.

Setting the document.body.style forces a full screen repaint, which avoids an occasional intermittent problems where the repaint badly fails after zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Found a very easily implemented fix.  Set the focus to a text element that has a font size of 50px on completion of the form.  It does not seem to work if the text element is hidden but hiding this element is easily done by setting the elements color properties to have no opacity.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way to do it, which seems to work well.

1. Set the meta tag to restrict the viewport to scale=1, which prevents zooming:

   < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
2. With javascript, change the meta tag 1/2 second later to
   allow zooming:

   setTimeout(function(){ document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content','width=device-width, initial-scale=1');}, 500);
3. Again with javascript, on orientation change, reload the page:

   window.onorientationchange = function(){window.location.reload();};

Every time you reorient the device, the page reloads, initially without zoom. But 1/2 second later, ability to zoom is restored.

Comment: Answering a question 5 years after it was asked is something..
Unfortunately this is not how the web works in 2015. You DON'T reload the page when the user rotates his device.