# iPhone UIWebView width does not fit after zooming operation + UIInterfaceOrientation change

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, width, zooming, autoresize

I created a bare bones iPhone app with a UIWebView (Scales Page to Fit = YES, shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation = YES) and loaded a webpage, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/

Rotating the device shows that UIWebView is auto-resized to fit the width. Good.

**Incorrect**: Zoom into the page and zoom out. Now rotating the device shows UIWebView in a weird width in one of the orientation (if u zoom in landscape, the portrait width is weird, vice versa). This behavior is fixed only when you navigate to another page.

**Correct**: Load the same URL in Mobile Safari. Rotating works & the width fits regardless of the zooming exercise.

Is this a UIWebView bug (probably not)? Or is there something that needs to be done to make things "just work" like in Mobile Safari?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found something that worked for me. The problem is that when uiwebview changes its orientation web contents are zoommed to fit with viewport. But zoomscale parameter of scrollview subview is not updated correctly (nor are updated minimumZoomScale nor maximumZoomScale

Then we need to do it manually at `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    CGFloat ratioAspect = webview.bounds.size.width/webview.bounds.size.height;
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            // Going to Portrait mode
            for (UIScrollView *scroll in [webview subviews]) { //we get the scrollview 
                // Make sure it really is a scroll view and reset the zoom scale.
                if ([scroll respondsToSelector:@selector(setZoomScale:)]){
                    scroll.minimumZoomScale = scroll.minimumZoomScale/ratioAspect;
                    scroll.maximumZoomScale = scroll.maximumZoomScale/ratioAspect;
                    [scroll setZoomScale:(scroll.zoomScale/ratioAspect) animated:YES];
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            // Going to Landscape mode
            for (UIScrollView *scroll in [webview subviews]) { //we get the scrollview 
                // Make sure it really is a scroll view and reset the zoom scale.
                if ([scroll respondsToSelector:@selector(setZoomScale:)]){
                    scroll.minimumZoomScale = scroll.minimumZoomScale *ratioAspect;
                    scroll.maximumZoomScale = scroll.maximumZoomScale *ratioAspect;
                    [scroll setZoomScale:(scroll.zoomScale*ratioAspect) animated:YES];
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I've fixed up the code so it is easier for anyone to implement into their ViewController.m (code is also duplicated to https://gist.github.com/834907 )

Comment: It still does some weird things with the animation, but thanks ;) It's better than it was before! I wonder exactly what Apple do to cater for this...me thinks they've got some kind of undocumented class that provides a fix.

Comment: Thanks - bit jumpy, but better than before.

Comment: @M Penades it works perfectly thanks it save me form a lot of problems.thanks buddy

Answer (score 4):

I've tried the solution from M Penades and this seems to work for me as well.

The only issue that I'm experiencing is that when running this on a 3Gs the rotation is unfortunately not very smooth.

I'm therefore now using a different approach:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

[super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];

CGFloat scale = browserWebView.contentScaleFactor;
NSString *javaStuff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;", scale];
[browserWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaStuff];

}
```

Best Regards,
Ralph

Comment: it does work for the Skew the UIWebView 
`M Penades` answer works perfectly. another bad thing in this answer is that every time when the device rotate javascript would call this 'll lead to the memory warning.So Above answer is best.

Comment: I'm using this in iOS8 inside -viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: to force the resize of the internal UIWebBrowserView component after a rotation. The accepted answer didn't work.

Comment: @Jano, can you explain in details what exactly did you do, I have the same problem - the UIWebBrowserView is misplaced when rotated on ios8

Comment: @Martin -(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{ CGFloat scale = self.webView.contentScaleFactor;NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;", scale];[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js]; }

Answer (score 4):

```
- (UIScrollView *)findScrollViewInsideView:(UIView *)view
{
    for(UIView *subview in view.subviews){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
            return (UIScrollView *)subview;
        }

        UIScrollView *foundScrollView = [self findScrollViewInsideView:subview];
        if (foundScrollView){
            return foundScrollView;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    switch (self.interfaceOrientation){
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        {
            UIScrollView *webViewScrollView = ([self.webView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)])
                ? self.webView.scrollView
                : [self findScrollViewInsideView:self.webView];

            [webViewScrollView setZoomScale:1.01f animated:YES];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

try this code, it insignificantly changes zoom level (1.01) to allow UIWebView increase content size in landscape mode

findScrollViewInsideView: method added to support ios4

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this problem, but I gotta say I'm not a huge fan of it. It works great, but the solution actually causes another problem. I have a fix for the secondary issue, but it takes a bit of effort.

Just keep in mind that since OS3.2 or iOS4 (not sure which) UIWebView's direct subview is now UIScrollView instead of UIScroller, so we can do a lot more with it. Also, since accessing subviews of a View is not a private action, neither is using a subview that is casted as a documented view we can do a lot with the UIWebView without breaking the rules.

First we need to get the UIScrollView from the UIWebview:

```
UIScrollView *sview = [[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now we need to change the delegate of this scrollview so we can override scrollview delegate calls (which may actually be the cause of a secondary bug as a result of this solution, which I'll share in a moment):

```
sview.delegate = self;
```

Now, if you try it at this point, zooming is broken. We need to implement a UIScrollViewDelegate method to fix it. add:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    UIView *webBrowserView = [[scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:10];
    return webBrowserView;
}
```

webBrowserView is actually a UIWebBrowserView, but that isn't a documented class, so we are just going to treat it as a UIView.

Now run your app, zoom in and then zoom out the webpage. Rotate, and it should appear correctly.

This does cause a rather large bug, that is perhaps worse than the original.

If you zoom in and then rotate, you will loose scrolling ability, but your view will be zoomed in still. Here is the fix To complete the whole thing.

First, we need to keep track of a few numbers, and have a flag defined:

I have these defined in my h file:

```
BOOL updateZoomData;
float zoomData; //this holds the scale at which we are zoomed in, scrollView.zoomScale
CGPoint zoomOffset; //this holds the scrollView.contentOffset
CGSize zoomContentSize; //this holds the scrollView.contentSize
```

You may think you can just grab these numbers from UIScrollView, but when you need them, they will have changed, so we need them stored elsewhere.

We need to use another delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if(updateZoomData){
        zoomData = scrollView.zoomScale;
        zoomOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
        zoomContentSize = scrollView.contentSize;
    }
}
```

Now it gets into a mess I feel.

We need to track rotation, so you'll need to add this to your viewDidLoad, loadView, or whatever method you use to register notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
            selector:@selector(webViewOrientationChanged:) 
            name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification 
            object:nil];
```

and create this method:

```
- (void)webViewOrientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
    updateZoomData = NO;
    [self performSelector:@selector(adjustWithZoomData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

So now anytime you rotate webViewOrientationChange will be called. The reason performSelector is delayed for 0.0 seconds is because we want to call adjustWithZoomData on the next runloop. If you call it directly, the adjustWithZoomData will adjust for the previous orientation.

Here is the adjustWithZoomData method:

```
- (void)adjustWithZoomData{
    UIScrollView *sview = [[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    [sview setZoomScale:zoomData animated:YES];
    [sview setContentOffset:zoomOffset animated:YES]; 
    [sview setContentSize:zoomContentSize];
    updateZoomData = YES;
}
```

Thats it! Now when you rotate it will maintain zoom, and roughly maintain the correct offset. If anyone wants to do the math on how to get the exact correct offset then go for it!

Comment: I guess I didn't mention, I think this is a bug in the first place.

Comment: I've also notice that this breaks double tapping for zoom out, sortof.

Comment: Hi maxpower, is there a documentation on the views-array of a UIWebView? If WebBrowserView is objectAtIdx:10, which entry whould be pdf/jpg/png-documents loaded directly into the UIWebView?

Comment: @iFloh - This is completely undocumented, and subject to change in the future, so I'd be very careful about using something like this in a shipping application.  If Apple alters the way this view works (as they frequently do for undocumented UI elements like this), your application could break.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this myself and found out some more information:

Issues when changing zoom:

1. Safari often doesn't repaint properly (if at all) even though zoom level changed.
2. Changing the width forces a repaint.
3. you would think width=device-width in landscape would use 1024 but it seems to use 768 (screen.width happens too).

e.g. if current width is 1024 and you want to zoom from 1 to 1.5 in landscape you could:

- change combination of width and zoom e.g. width to 2048 and zoom to 0.75
- change width to 1023 (ugly aliasing?)
- change width to say 1023, then next line back to 1024 (double repaint, but at least window is repainted).

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I didn't use the solution by M Penades in the end (and forgot to update this post! sorry).

What I did was to resize the entire document (and change my font-size to keep things proportionate). That apparently fixed the issue.

However, my UIWebView is only for loading my own HTML & CSS from the iOS filesystem - if you're building a general purpose web browser, this trick may not work as well.

ViewController.m

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)) {
                [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.className = 'ppad'"];
            } else {
                [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.className = 'pphone'"];
            }
            break;
        default:
            if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)) {
                [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.className = 'lpad'"];
            } else {
                [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.className = 'lphone'"];
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And app.css

```
html>body.pphone { font-size:12px; width: 980px; }
html>body.lphone { font-size:18px; width: 1470px; }
html>body.ppad { font-size:12px; width: 768px; }
html>body.lpad { font-size:15.99999996px; width: 1024px; }
```

Gist at https://gist.github.com/d6589584944685909ae5

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this because i have also faced the same problem and here i am following the `M Penades` Approach.`M Penades` 's Answer woks good only for case if user does not Skew(pinch Out) the Webview then rotate the device and repeat this process .then Content Size of UiwebView gets reduce gradually. so that was the issue came in `M Penades` Answer. so I have fixed that issue  too and my code is as below.

1) For This I set the Pinch Gesture so that when User Skew The UIwebView could check the Scaled size of UIwebView.
        //One This Please import The `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` Protocol in '.h file'

```
     //call below method in ViewDidLoad Method for setting the Pinch gesture 

- (void)setPinchgesture
{
     UIPinchGestureRecognizer * pinchgesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didPinchWebView:)];

    [pinchgesture setDelegate:self];

    [htmlWebView addGestureRecognizer:pinchgesture];
    [pinchgesture release];
   // here htmlWebView is WebView user zoomingIn/Out 

}
   //Allow The allow simultaneous recognition

  - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer   *)otherGestureRecognizer
  {
     return YES;
  }
```

Returning YES is guaranteed to allow simultaneous recognition. returning NO is not guaranteed to prevent simultaneous recognition, as the other gesture's delegate may return YES

```
 -(void)didPinchWebView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)gestsure
   {
   //check if the Scaled Fator is same is normal scaling factor the allow set Flag True.
    if(gestsure.scale<=1.0)
    {
    isPinchOut = TRUE;

    }
    else// otherwise Set false
    {
    isPinchOut = FALSE;
   }
  NSLog(@"Hello Pinch %f",gestsure.scale);
}
```

If User Hase Pinch In/Out The Web View in that Case Just Set THat Zooming Factor .
    SO that WebView Can Adjust Its ContentSize as Oreintaion Changed.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation   duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

   //Allow the Execution of below code when user has Skewed the UIWebView and Adjust the Content Size of UiwebView.

  if(isPinchOut){
  CGFloat ratioAspect = htmlWebView.bounds.size.width/htmlWebView.bounds.size.height;
  switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        // Going to Portrait mode
        for (UIScrollView *scroll in [htmlWebView subviews]) { //we get the scrollview
            // Make sure it really is a scroll view and reset the zoom scale.
            if ([scroll respondsToSelector:@selector(setZoomScale:)]){
                scroll.minimumZoomScale = scroll.minimumZoomScale/ratioAspect;
                scroll.maximumZoomScale = scroll.maximumZoomScale/ratioAspect;
                [scroll setZoomScale:(scroll.zoomScale/ratioAspect) animated:YES];
            }
        }
        break;

    default:
        // Going to Landscape mode
        for (UIScrollView *scroll in [htmlWebView subviews]) { //we get the scrollview
            // Make sure it really is a scroll view and reset the zoom scale.
            if ([scroll respondsToSelector:@selector(setZoomScale:)]){
                scroll.minimumZoomScale = scroll.minimumZoomScale *ratioAspect;
                scroll.maximumZoomScale = scroll.maximumZoomScale *ratioAspect;
                [scroll setZoomScale:(scroll.zoomScale*ratioAspect) animated:YES];
            }
        }
        break;
     }
  }

}
```

This Works perfectly for even user skew the UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

On rotation, try setting the scrollView zoomScale to 0.
See my full answer here: [UIWebView content not adjusted to new frame after rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823648/uiwebview-content-not-adjusted-to-new-frame-after-rotation/28678202#28678202)