# UIWebView content not adjusted to new frame after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have an e-mail application,
which shows the content in an `UIWebView` inside an `UISplitViewController`.
Everything works fine until i rotate the device, when already zoomed in/out in the `UIWebView`.
When rotating the device, i adjust the frame of the `UIWebView` in

`- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

The problem is, when i zoomed in/out in the `UIWebView`and then rotate the device.
The content isn't resized to it's new frame, which leads to a gray/black border in the content, or the content can be scrolled horizontal.

Addional information:
The `UIWebView`is a subview on a `UIScrollView` which can be scrolled.
When the `UIWebView`is totally visible the `scrollEnabled`of the `UIScrollView`is disabled and the `UIWebView` can be scrolled.

[image: Landscape_Correct]
Above picture shows the `UIWebView`in landscape when selecting an email.
This is the state before rotating in both cases.
[image: Portrait_Without_Zooming]
**[Not zoomed before rotating]**Above picture shows that the `UIWebView` is correctly resizing the content to it's new frame.
[image: Portrait_With_Zooming]
**[Zoomed before rotating]**Above picture shows the `UIWebView` after zooming in landscape and then rotating to portrait
-> content isn't correctly shown
Information of the `UIWebView.scrollView` in
 `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation`:
`<_UIWebViewScrollView: 0xb1322a0; frame = (0 0; 768 960); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xb1321d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xb132270>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>`
frame is correct!

Edit: Solution!!
i managed to solve it by updating the viewport width after rotating the device
`CGFloat fll_width = self.view.frame.size.width;
NSString* adsl_javascript_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var setViewPortScript = document.createElement('meta');\
setViewPortScript.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');\
setViewPortScript.setAttribute('content', 'width = %f');\
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(setViewPortScript);", fll_width];
[adsc_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:adsl_javascript_string];`

Comment: You are aware that a `UIWebView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so I am just wondering what the logic is with the extra `UIScrollView` everything you have described can be achieved with just the `UIWebView`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i managed to solve it by updating the viewport width after rotating the device

```
CGFloat fll_width = self.view.frame.size.width;
NSString* adsl_javascript_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var setViewPortScript = document.createElement('meta');\
     setViewPortScript.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');\
     setViewPortScript.setAttribute('content', 'width = %f');\
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(setViewPortScript);", fll_width];
[adsc_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:adsl_javascript_string];
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug also in iOS 7 and iOS 8.
A fix would be this:

First resize the frame on layout changes:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    _webView.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

Then on the rotation callback reset the zoomScale to 0. Yes, 0!

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    // Allow the animation to complete
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_webView.scrollView setZoomScale:0 animated:YES];
    });
}
```

You can also use the new function

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    // Allow the animation to complete
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_webView.scrollView setZoomScale:0 animated:YES];
    });
}
```