# Web view width issue on orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am facing issue with webView on orientation change, when orientation gets changed from Portrait to landscape, webviews width increases. Now when I change orientation to portrait, webviews width still remain same as landscape mode. Its adding extra black space on right of page and webview is allowing to scroll towards it. Is there any way by which I can minimize webview's scroll width for portrait mode.

I am using following code for orientation support for webpage.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"\nwebViewDidFinishLoad\n");

    switch (self.interfaceOrientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.__defineGetter__('orientation',function(){return 0;});window.onorientationchange();"];
            NSLog(@"\nUIDeviceOrientationPortrait\n");
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.__defineGetter__('orientation',function(){return 90;});window.onorientationchange();"];
            NSLog(@"\nUIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft\n");
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.__defineGetter__('orientation',function(){return -90;});window.onorientationchange();"];
            NSLog(@"\nUIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight\n");
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.__defineGetter__('orientation',function(){return 180;});window.onorientationchange();"];
            NSLog(@"\nUIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown\n");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

See this thread on orientation issues with UIWebView... [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890673/iphone-uiwebview-width-does-not-fit-after-zooming-operation-uiinterfaceorientat)