# UIWebView autosize issue only on iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiwebview

I am trying to figure out how to fix this bug that only occurs on iOS 4.3. When the application launches, it displays a PDF that is scaled to fit in the UIWebView. It behaves perfectly until you pinch to zoom on the document, and then rotate it, leaving behind a black area. If you don't pinch to zoom, it doesn't leave the black area. I don't understand why this is a iOS 4.3 only issue.
Screenshot of the issue: I've been trying to solve this problem awhile now, and would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

[image]

Screenshots of the .xib settings:

[image] [image] [image]

The code I'm using is:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
   UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize webView;

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    return YES;
    } else {
    return (interfaceOrientation !=
            UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress]; NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall there being a few bugs with UIWebView and rotation in the past. I remember specifically that there were some rendering and resizing issues. In all honesty, if it has worked since iOS 4.3 then I think you shouldn't even bother trying to fix the issue -- in all likelihood the fix you will come up with will be hacky and irrelevant at this point.

That being said, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890673/iphone-uiwebview-width-does-not-fit-after-zooming-operation-uiinterfaceorienta) might help you solve the problem.

Comment: That link you provided was helpful. I guess I won't even bother with fixing it, as there is hardly anyone on iOS 4.3 still?

Answer (score 0):

If it works in iOS6, it may because the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is never be called in it. The way to handle rotation is changed in iOS6. It happened to work in your code.

Another possible solution is to use delegate of webview to wait untill it's loaded then add it to the view.