# ios phonegap "black bar" after orientation change

Tags: ios, cordova, pinchzoom

ios (ipad 3 or iphone 5) phonegap (currently latest 3.4.0) application with very simple html and inline css: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fmq87E2U

The problem is that if I am on landscape orientation, change to portrait, unzoom, and then change back to landscape, then a black vertical bar appears on the right of the screen until I do any pinch/zoom.

screenshots:

1. [start app on landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tClL.png)
2. [rotate to portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09eaN.png)
3. [pinch-unzoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6cnv.png)
4. [rotate back to landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onk77.png) (problem "black area" in this shot at the right hand side)

No matter what I do via CSS when the black bar appers, nothing can change this situation (I've even tried webkit rotate, scale but all affect the visible part of the page). I also tried `window.resizeTo` in order to trigger a browser "repaint" or something but no luck.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

This bug cannot be reproduced as a webpage on the ipad or iphone safari. On orientation change the screen adapts correctly.

Comment: It appears that your webView is not scaling. Look into webView.scalesPageToFit property. This is an ObjC fix, not CSS.

Comment: I don't have access to that stuff since I build with phonegap build.

Comment: In config.xml, is <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true"/> set? Defaults to false, I believe.

Comment: Yes. But in any case this setting doesn't play any role since the pinch zoom is being enabled via the `meta` tag.

Comment: Just a thought, not sure how pg build handles webView props.

Comment: @gro: I compiled on ios and after setting `self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;` the problem was not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to simply reload the page on orientation change. The phonegap browser adapts the zoom.

```
var originalPageLoadOrientation = window.orientation;
$(window).on("orientationchange", function() {
    // just to avoid initial orientationchange which is called on page load
    if (originalPageLoadOrientation==window.orientation) return;
    location.reload();
});
```

This of course may have other implications in the app. (e.g if the app is a complex single page application where reloading the whole page restarts everything).

**Edit**: Instead of `location.reload();` a better way is to do `location.href = location.href;`. The latter seems to avoid a visible flashing of the display.

Answer (score 1):

How about the css below:

```
position:fixed;
width:100%;
```

Comment: Thanks for the guess. Unfortunately placing this on any of the 3 css blocks of my provided html (`html`, `body`, `#container`) breaks my requirements since the user can no longer perform step 3 (unzoom).

Answer (score 1):

The problem originates from the fact that the `#container` width is larger than the portrait width in pixels, thus the user has to manually unzoom (step 3). Changing orientation to landscape after unzooming (step 4) doesn't work well inside the phonegap browser (it works in the regular browser though).

So a solution I found is:

1. force the user to be unable to nativelly unzoom below 1 using `minimum-scale=1` in the viewport (this solves the black bar problem)
2. use css zoom to adapt the `#container` dynamically on every orientation change thus making large content (e.g 900px wide) fit on smaller screens (e.g portrait ipad):

code

```
$(window).on("orientationchange", function() {
    var landscape = Math.abs(window.orientation)==90;
    var width = landscape?screen.height:screen.width;
    var divWidth = 900;
    $('#container').attr("style", "zoom: " + (width/divWidth));
});
```

The above is a workaround though. The real bug that is that the browser of phonegap doesn't recover from that situation (step 4) like the real browser does by adapting the native zoom automatically.

Comment: The native iOS web view (`UIWebView`) has this exact same problem until you set its `opaque` property to `NO`.

Answer (score 1):

fwiw, this issue has been discussed for many years, now. (example [iPhone UIWebView width does not fit after zooming operation + UIInterfaceOrientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890673/iphone-uiwebview-width-does-not-fit-after-zooming-operation-uiinterfaceorienta?rq=1) ). And, unfortunately, this issue still exists.

@cherovium here is another spin on your suggested work around without having to track the orientation.

```
$(window).on("orientationchange", function() {
             //to avoid all other scenarios but the OP's
             if (window.outerWidth / window.innerWidth >= 1.0) return;
             location.href = location.href;
             //or location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Your link points to the actual source of the problem. The accepted solution worked for me as well when built in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a common problem with the `UIWebView` used in iOS apps, and it's fixed with just this line:

```
self.webView.opaque = NO;
```

I don't know if or how PhoneGap exposes this property of the web view, but if it is exposed turning off the opaque property should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I don't simply want to fill in the black area with a colour. I want the UIWebView to refresh it's native zoom so the content fits on screen.

Comment: I compiled nativelly and your suggestion didn't change anything. To make sure that I altered the value in the correct place, adding `self.webView.alpha = 0.7f;` did have an effect.