# mobile safari: device rotation causes bad scaling of website

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, zooming

i have a mobile website for iphone and ipad where i disable user zooming with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

this works fine as long as the site is in landscape mode. the width of the website is exactly the width of the screen.
then if i rotate the device into portrait mode it gets scaled down so that it fits the new (shorter) width. this is also ok.

but then if i rotate it back to landscape mode it is suddenly scaled to about 125% that means horizontal scrolling is now possible and zooming is not possible since initially disabled.

how can i make it back at 100% zoom when rotated back to landscape?

thanks!

Answer (score 17):

try experimenting with maximum-scale and minimum-scale like so

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
```

and see if you can achieve what you are looking for..

Comment: I just ran some rudimentary tests and the following worked wonders for me: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: This is a good workaround to what I feel is a bug in mobile safari. clamp's original metatag is how I normally set up my sites. I suspect there's something in the DOM in safari that doesn't behave as expected in some sites to mess with the page width that ultimately causes this problem.

Answer (score 8):

Disabling zoom is a bad idea. It's not a perfect solution, but targeting webkit's scaling of font size on orientation change can help minimize the problem. You would leave the head of the document with:

**`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`**

Then you would address the font-size scaling in your CSS like this:

```
body {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2.3rem;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
/* This prevents mobile Safari from freely adjusting font-size */**
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `maximum-scale` and `minimum-scale`to stop zooming don't really work because then you take away the user's ability to zoom.  That's really a bad idea because it makes your users with bad eyes angry that your website doesn't zoom, while other websites do...

I tried timeouts and all kinds of fancy javascript, then I found this:
https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix

via this related question: [How do I reset the scale/zoom of a web app on an orientation change on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557801/how-do-i-reset-the-scale-zoom-of-a-web-app-on-an-orientation-change-on-the-iphon)

On that post, Andrew Ashbacher posted a link to the code written by Scott Jehl:

```
/*! A fix for the iOS orientationchange zoom bug. Script by @scottjehl, rebound by @wilto.MIT License.*/(function(m){if(!(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(navigator.platform)&&navigator.userAgent.indexOf("AppleWebKit")>-1)){return}var l=m.document;if(!l.querySelector){return}var n=l.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]"),a=n&&n.getAttribute("content"),k=a+",maximum-scale=1",d=a+",maximum-scale=10",g=true,j,i,h,c;if(!n){return}function f(){n.setAttribute("content",d);g=true}function b(){n.setAttribute("content",k);g=false}function e(o){c=o.accelerationIncludingGravity;j=Math.abs(c.x);i=Math.abs(c.y);h=Math.abs(c.z);if(!m.orientation&&(j>7||((h>6&&i<8||h<8&&i>6)&&j>5))){if(g){b()}}else{if(!g){f()}}}m.addEventListener("orientationchange",f,false);m.addEventListener("devicemotion",e,false)})(this);
```

That is a solution wrapped nicely in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) so you don't have to worry about name-space issues.

Just drop it in to your script (not into `document.ready()` if you're using jQuery) and viola!

All it does is disable zoom on `devicemotion` events that indicate that `orientationchange` is imminent.  It's the best solution I've seen because it actually works and doesn't disable zoom.

EDIT: this approach is not always reliable, especially when you are holding the ipad at an angle.  also, i don't think this event is available to gen 1 ipads