# What does $(window).resize do? JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

So I had a look at jquery mobile, for my ipad webapp, and I saw this:

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Which, of course, I'm looking at because of this:
[how to resize / rezoom webpage in ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557971/how-to-resize-rezoom-webpage-in-ipad)

But the thing is, this window.resize doesn't do a darn thing for me. At least, I was expecting it to re-apply the maximum-scale and minimum-scale values

It does not. Am I missing something here, or is window.resize bunk?

UPDATE
I suppose i mean : does the window.resize fire after an orientation change on an ipad, and if so, does it cause the scales -minimum-scale and maximum-scale - to be reset?

Comment: No, it works. I tested it on my Samsung Smartphone and now its screen is twice as big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(window).resize` as per the api doc has two syntaxes: the first one is to bind a function to be executed upon resize, and the second one to trigger the callback to functions that listens to the `resize` event.

It does not do anything per se except provide you with a way to set up a listener for the event and manually trigger it if needed - so it won't reset any other properties

To the best of my knowledge, ipad orientation changes DO trigger resize events when using safari. However, if your app is using a native uiwebview, it is possible that orientation changes don't trigger it.