# jquery resize to mobile window iphone/android

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was wondering if there were any methods that would allow for my webpage to adjust to an iphone's or android's screen? i read about $(window).resize in [What does $(window).resize do? JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704359/what-does-window-resize-do-jquery-mobile), i read the documentation and am still confused. can someone provide an example for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(window).resize(...)` binds a callback for the *resize* event or triggers this event.

Bind a callback function, if the users resizes the browser window:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    alert('resize handler called');
});
```

If you want to call all listeners manually (without any parameters):

```
$(window).resize();
```

=== UPDATE ===

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ym8e7/).

=== UPDATE ===

I don't think that you can resize the window, but you can change the zoom level by changing the viewport scale (untested):

```
function changeZoomLevel(iScale) {
    var sViewport = '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=' + iScale + '">';
    var jViewport = $('meta[name="viewport"]');
    if (jViewport.length > 0) {
        jViewport.replaceWith(sViewport);
    } else {
        $('head').append(sViewport);
    }
}

var iScale = 0.5 // set or calculate a zoom value between 0 and 1
changeZoomLevel(iScale);
```

Comment: would the last option resize the entire window automatically?

Comment: Never, only call the callbacks.