# Improper page elements placement after orientation change on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, safari

I run some code to reposition elements on the page after window resize (desktop) or orientation change (iPad). I face the problem with improper repositioning of those elements I work with. What I do to reproduce this problem is:

1. Load the page in vertical orientation. Everything looks good.
2. Rotate the iPad by 90. Elements that should be repositioned, do it properly. Everything looks good.
3. Rotate the iPad back. The issue appears and looks like this:

[image: Improper repositioning of elements after rotation]

Here is how it should look like:

[image: Looks good here]

If I comment that code that repositions those elements, it all looks good except the elements. The same happens both in iPad Safari and iPad Chrome. If I do window resize on desktop browser, my code works fine.
Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in older iPads that didn't resize/zoom on orientation change. I'm not sure if it has been fixed in the latest OS.
Check here: [how to resize / rezoom webpage in ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557971/how-to-resize-rezoom-webpage-in-ipad)

Comment: From first sight it seems to be a solution. At least it helped now. Thanks!