# Rotating landscape to portrait iPad does not change the scaling of a web page

Tags: javascript, css, ipad

Initially it's showing fine when watching the page in portrait mode and it's fine when changing orientation from portrait to landscape but while changing from landscape to portrait, the web page goes in zoom-in mode and doesn't show the complete page anymore. For this I am using:

`width=device-width, minimum-width=768px, maximum-width=1024, initial-scale=0.75, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=2.0`

Any solution regarding same?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use maximum-scale=1.0.
If you want to be able to zoom the page manually there's a workaround with JS: [How do I reset the scale/zoom of a web app on an orientation change on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557801/how-do-i-reset-the-scale-zoom-of-a-web-app-on-an-orientation-change-on-the-iphon)