# A way to reset mobile browser zoom onSubmit?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I'm working on an interface for an application that requires staying on the same page and displaying a new message after submitting a form.

The issue is that mobile browsers will automatically zoom into the input fields (useful) when users are filling out the form but the zoom will then stay at that level after submission when I would want it to return to normal and display the confirmation message at a standard size.

Is there a way to return the browser zoom to normal with JavaScript (not jQuery) without refreshing the page?

Comment: Probably this post could help you in some way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557801/how-do-i-reset-the-scale-zoom-of-a-web-app-on-an-orientation-change-on-the-iphon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For safari on mobile you cant use `maximum-scale=1.0` then reset it back to `maximum-scale=10.0`. This will make it so users are only allowed to zoom in x1. Then you reset it back to x10.

Comment: `For safari on mobile you cant use`: is *can't* on purpose? This doesn't fit in your sentence structure very well