# javascript: interstitial ads on mobile - how do you handle zoom?

Tags: javascript, css, ads, interstitial

I have a script that runs on a publisher's site.
I want to show an interstitial ad upon entrance to site. I have access to conventional ads.
The problem is that publishers treat their mobile sites differently or not at all.
You can go to a site with no "meta name="viewport"" and initial scale and/or stumble upon different scales or zooms.
So if I have a 320x480 ad, it won't look good in **all** the 320x480 devices since I don't know the zoom/scale state.
As I read, even if I can tell the scale, it's almost impossible to handle it and have a X-Browser support.
Open a new window or navigate to my own URL to show the ad is out of the question.

Can you recommend on a solution for this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, no one answered :(
So far I thought of this method, will be happy to hear your thoughts.

By reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379428/2362973) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094906/2362973) one, I can modify the viewport properties in runtime.
That's good and enables me to show the ad on scale 1 regardless the user scale or zoom.

The problem is, how to get back to the previous scale once the ad is not shown anymore? How can I save the current scale/zoom and set it back when I need?
Saving the content alone is not enough because the user can change the zoom after page load.
Thanks.

EDIT:

So this is what I come up with:

1. querySelector for the viewport
2. If exist, save the 'content' data, remove the width if exist and add the CURRENT_WIDTH. If not, create a viewport with only CURRENT_WIDTH as a parameter
3. Set new attributes to 'content' as follows:

> viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');

4. Restore viewport attributes when needed

Comment: Maybe you can enable scalability again with JavaScript when the ad is closed by the user.

Comment: This is what I want to do but how can I go back to the previous scale?