# iOS css error after I change some css style by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

At first, I have set `user-scalable=no` and `width=device-width`.

My meta content is `<meta content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />`

And the begin view like this.

[image]

When I click a button in an div and change the css style width `$('#A').toggleClass('B')`. Then the view like this.

[image]

The buttons in a div container. The div contain is the same size as device and it's css `overflow: hidden.`

After I click a button and change its style. Both `overflow` and `user-scalable=no` are fail.

How to deal with it?

Comment: My first thought is - Do you have `width=device-width` set for the viewport?

Comment: @drip Of course, I have set it

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.

See here: [How do I reset the scale/zoom of a web app on an orientation change on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557801/how-do-i-reset-the-scale-zoom-of-a-web-app-on-an-orientation-change-on-the-iphon)

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
if (viewportmeta) {
    viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0';
    document.body.addEventListener('gesturestart', function () {
        viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6';
    }, false);
}
```

}